# Why am I getting access denied error Reverse Linked List in C

Tags: c, runtime-error, doubly-linked-list

Always get the error code. I'm trying to reverse transverse the list and print.
Is there something I'm missing in the creation of the list?
I can print the list normal but just not reversed
Any help would be appreciated

```
struct stNode {
    char            *pName;
    double          avg;
    struct stNode   *next;
    struct stNode   *prev;
}; //stNode
typedef struct stNode Node;

void  createList(Node **head, Node **tail) {
    Node* tmp;
    Node* x;

    for(int i = 0;i < INPUTSIZE; i++){
        //stores values in nodes
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tmp->avg = f1input_avg[i];
        tmp->pName = f1input_name[i];
        tmp->next = NULL;

        //If list is empty
        if( *head == NULL){
            *head  = tmp;
        }
        //Creates subsequent nodes
        else{
            x = *head;
            while(x->next != NULL){
                x = x->next;
            }
            x->next = tmp;
        }
    }
} // createList

void RevprintList(Node *head){
         Node        *cur = NULL;


    printf("=======Reversed List =======\n");
    cur = head;
    while (cur->next != NULL) {
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    while (cur != head){
        printf("%-15s %5.2lf\n", cur->pName, cur->avg);
        cur = cur->prev;
    }
}

int main() {
    Node        *head = NULL;
    Node        *tail = NULL;

    createList(&head, &tail);
    printList(head);
    RevprintList(head);
    freeList(&head, &tail);
}
```

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: You should include the code that makes the `createList` and `RevprintList` calls.

Comment: Process terminated with status -1073741819 (11 minute(s), 46 second(s)) This is all I get

Comment: This is a good time to learn to use a debugger. At a minimum it will immediately give you the exact line of code that triggers the crash and can also be used to examine the program as it runs. And where does "access denied" come from?

Comment: The `prev` pointer is never set. So there's no way traversing backwards with that pointer  has any chance of working.